# How to read a space-delimited text file with empty columns

Tags: c#, csv, whitespace, streamreader

I'm trying to read a space-delimited file using `StreamReader`.

For this I'm reading the file line by line split them into arrays and reading a specific data by providing an index.

The problem is when in some rows a column is empty. This causes the program to reach the wrong item.

```
col1       col2      col3
a             b           c
d                         e
f             g           h
```

For example, I'm having problems with the second row.

Comment: Do you know the exact number of spaces between elements in rows (for example between a and b) ? Is this number is fixed or arbitrary ?

Comment: @Fabjan Unfortunately I don't

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have fixed width columns you wont know which value should be empty, if you have control over the format you should wrap values in quotes, or have a CSV format with quotes for value wrapping, espacing inner quotes, you can then have the luxury of view if in excel :-) for free.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Answer (score 1):

I can see two approaches on this.

1. Use exact width/spaces to find element positioning inside row
2. Analyze element positions inside every row in case when you have less than three elements. Compare x position of each element to x positions of headers, for example:

   ```
       string header = "col1       col2      col3";
       string row1 =   "adfgdgdfg              c";

       int[] headerPoss = { header.IndexOf("col1"), header.IndexOf("col2"), header.IndexOf("col3") };

       string[] row1Elements = row1.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

       int[] rowElementsPos = new int[row1Elements.Length];

       for (int i = 0; i < row1Elements.Length; i++)
           rowElementsPos[i] = row1.IndexOf(row1Elements[i]);

       for (int i = 0; i < row1Elements.Length; i++)
       {                
           Console.WriteLine("This element is from column {0}", headerPoss.Min(hp => Math.Abs(hp - rowElementsPos[i])) + 1);
       }
       Console.ReadKey();
   ```

Output :

[image]